# Magento 2 Fonts Preload <font> head

Tags: magento2.3

I am adding the fonts as specified in magento 2.3 documentation however i am getting the error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'font': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ).
```

I am adding font as

```
<font src="fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add like this in your xml file :

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2" as="font"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. So far all good however it is giving me this error

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'link', attribute 'crossorigin': The attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.`

Comment: Thanks. Happy coding !! Just remove crossorigin attribute if you added in link tag.

Comment: Thank you.
I did the same however more problems coming with magneto. If i put multiple fonts as `<link rel="preload" src="fonts/icomoon.woff" as="font"/>
        <link rel="preload" src="fonts/VarelaRound-Regular-webfont.woff" as="font"/>` preloading it not loading and giving me error that 
`Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Merge for content type 'woff' is not supported.
`

**What i did**
I put the same in Design > configuration > Header and now it works but in default_head_blocks.xml its not working at all

Comment: It's really strange..!! It should be working but maybe something wrong in your file.

Comment: this is not working at Magento 2.3.7